# Сглаживание изображения в imagebox в WF

Tags: c#, winforms, изображения

При попытке отобразить изображение с другим разрешением, но с одинаковыми пропорциями на imagebox в WF, происходит сглаживание этого изображения. Например, есть картинка 100x100 пикселей, которую я помещаю в imagebox 400x400:
[image: Пример сглаживания в imagebox]

Size-Mode стоит в StretchImage. Как отключить это сглаживание в imagebox?

Comment: никак, если верить документации на MSDN.